# POST data getting lost: Content Length = 0

Tags: iphone, ios, nginx, asihttprequest, uwsgi

I am randomly getting `content-length = 0` errors on my server with the following setup:

iPhone `POST's` data `synchronously` using `ASIFormDataRequest` to the `nginx proxy for UWSGI` server.

The error appears randomly maybe once out of 200 requests.

I have searched for this problem but didn't find any clear answer. One of the post mentioned weird `ASIHTTPRequest` behavior, bug. But it's not for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found an answer.

There is a problem in ASIHTTPRequest with a persistant connections as described here: https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/issues/94

The workarround is to use

```
[request setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:NO];
```

This was fixed in a newer version of the ASIHTTPRequest.